# ReactJS: Update UI when state changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, settimeout

I'm relativly new to ReactJS and I'm trying to create a Sudoku Solver.

When I update the state I want the UI also to update, therefore the user can see what the algorithm is doing.

With my current code the UI updates only at the end and fills the whole sudoku board at once.

I tried to use `setTimeout()` in verious places but it didn't work out.

**Here is my React Class:**

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.sass';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { board: [
        ["5","3",".",".","7",".",".",".","."],
        ["6",".",".","1","9","5",".",".","."],
        [".","9","8",".",".",".",".","6","."],
        ["8",".",".",".","6",".",".",".","3"],
        ["4",".",".","8",".","3",".",".","1"],
        ["7",".",".",".","2",".",".",".","6"],
        [".","6",".",".",".",".","2","8","."],
        [".",".",".","4","1","9",".",".","5"],
        [".",".",".",".","8",".",".","7","9"]
      ]
    };
  }

  createTable = () => {
    let table = [];

    for(let row = 0; row < this.state.board.length; row++) {
      let children = [];

      for(let col = 0; col < this.state.board[0].length; col++) {
        children.push(<td>{this.state.board[row][col]}</td>)
      }
      table.push(<tr>{children}</tr>)
    }
    return table
  }

  solveSudoku = board => {
    for(let row = 0; row < board.length; row++) {
        for(let col = 0; col < board[row].length; col++) {
          if(board[row][col] === '.') {
            for(let num = 1; num <= 9; num++) {
              // Check if valid
              if(this.isValid(board, row, col, num)) {
                board[row][col] = num.toString();
                this.setState(board);

                if(this.solveSudoku(board)) {
                  this.setState(board);
                  return true;
                } else {
                  board[row][col] = '.';
                  this.setState(board);
                }
              }
            }
            return false;
          }
        }
      }
      return true;
  }

  isValid = (board, row, col, num) => {
    for(let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
      // Check row
      if(parseInt(board[row][i]) === num) {
        return false;
      // Check column
      } else if(parseInt(board[i][col]) === num) {
        return false;
      // Check Subgrid
      } else if(parseInt(board[3 * (Math.floor(row / 3)) + Math.floor(i / 3)][3 * (Math.floor(col / 3)) + i % 3]) === num) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            {this.createTable()}
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={() => this.solveSudoku(this.state.board)}>Solve</Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I have yet to read all of your codes but you probably should call `this.setState({ board })` instead of `this.setState(board)`.

Comment: The very simple workaround could be setting state empty at the entry of update function.

Comment: @dev_junwen I updated my code, but it's still not working

Comment: I've copied your code and tested, it seems to be working fine

Comment: @dev_junwen Is the UI updating every number at once, therefore the user can see what the algorithm is doing?

Comment: @Dario You want the board to solve itself step by step is it ?

Comment: @dev_junwen yes thats it

Answer (score -1):

The UI automatically rerenders on either state change or prop change.
It looks like you are incorrectly setting the state.

setState should include a new instance of state which is an object.
so should look like this: this.setState({newState});

Comment: also your state should be immutable so you will want to copy your board into a new object instead of mutating this.state.board.

const newBoard = {...board}
then you can mutate newBoard and call this.setState({board: newBoard})